# Running fixup_bundle for a specific target (PACKAGE)

Tags: cmake, cpack

I would like to incorporate external dlls when running CPACK without enumerating all of them (by explicitly calling INSTALL(FILE ...) )

Employing **fixup_bundle** it is possible to fixup all the executables in the install folder (**CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX**) by copying the required libraries.

```
INSTALL(CODE "
   include(BundleUtilities)
   fixup_bundle(\"${APPS}\"   \"\"   \"${DIRS}\")
   " DESTINATION bin COMPONENT Runtime)
```

This code is executed when building the **INSTALL** target and will handle only elements present inside the folder CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.

What I would like to do instead is to run **fixup_bundle** during the building of the **PACKAGE** target which is added by CPACK. in this way the install script generated will also include externa libraries.

Did anyone managed  to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found so far do not rely on fixup_bundle but on listing all files that have to be installed for the runtime configuration (e.g. all dlls).

Given a target you can recover the associated runtime file and add it to the INSTALL project:

```
#get dll location
get_target_property(BIN_F ${target} LOCATION_${Configuration}) 

#copy to the bin folder
install(FILES ${BIN_F} DESTINATION ${destinationFolder} 
                    CONFIGURATIONS ${Configuration} 
                         COMPONENT Runtime)
```

You then can recurse over the target dependenices to perform the same two operations using

```
get_target_property(link_libs ${target} INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)
```